# Java: Offsetting a byte[] without performing a copy operation

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, arrays

I was wondering if it is possible, access a `byte[]` with an offset without having to copy data around?
I've looked at `Arrays.*`, `ByteArrayInputStream` and `System.arraycopy`, but they all require to allocate a new `byte[]` to copy to.

What I want is an equivalent to this in `C++`:

```
char* buffer = new char[256];
char* buf_offset = buffer + 128; // <- no copy
```

Comment: There is no direct equivalent for this in Java, but for example `String` is implemented to achieve a very similar thing: `substring()` returns a new `String` instance that internally uses the exact same `char[]` as the original. That would be the idiomatic Java way.

Comment: That's why APIs that take `byte` arrays would very often have two extra parameters - for `offset` and `length` :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: `substring()` *can* work that way, but doesn't have to. I believe the Sun JRE changed recently around that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, oracle changed substring()..................

Comment: @JonSkeet How recently would that be? Java 8? Since in [Java 7 it still stands](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#645).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik see the latest 7u9 version.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You should check more recent builds, b147 is ancient. I think it was around the 1.7u6

Comment: @DanielTeply Could you provide a link? b147 is 17 months old.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Download any recent JDK (sources are included - it's far easier than finding stuff in the repos: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/).

Comment: @DanielTeply I hate big downloads, so I did manage in the meantime to dig it up there, it's quite an exhausting experience. It would be really nice of Grepcode if they kept up with the JDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `ByteBuffer` around instead. It can be advanced, duplicated, sliced without copying.

ByteBuffer is really ugly and counter-intuitive. However it's being used extensively in new JDK APIs, so one can probably accept that it's a basic type.

Comment: For this small task I need it for, it's just fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no equivalent of that. You'll just need to keep track of the offset yourself. You could always create a class to encapsulate the (data, offset) pair.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I guess I have to live with that. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to create a class for that. `ByteBuffer` does exactly that (amongst other things).

Comment: @Dunes: The "amongst other things" is the problem though - if I want to deal with an API which is really *just* an array and an offset, I'd rather have just that than use `ByteBuffer` with all its other operations.

Comment: ByteBuffer is really ugly and counter-intuitive. However it's being used extensively in new JDK APIs, so one can probably accept that it's a basic type.

Comment: @irreputable: It's far from *basic*. It's available out of the box, certainly, but that's far from a description of "basic".

Comment: I'm curious as to what you guys have against ByteBuffer. By extra stuff I meant the distinction between direct and non-direct buffers and creating different views of the buffer (eg. FloatBuffer). Not bloated, but not basic either.

Comment: @Dunes: Exactly - all kinds of stuff which *really* isn't needed if the OP simply wants a byte array. There's enough confusing stuff in the API, that I'd personally just keep what I need: an array and an offset.